# LongListSelector and NavigationService.GoBack()

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector, windows-phone-8.1, navigationservice

Simply the problem is:

1. I select one item on LLS, item template extends and there are 4 buttons.
2. Click one of them and navigate another page.
3. Then navigate back with NavigationService.GoBack() [Here is the result](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CB98DD0B6654BA09!113)

I selected 3rd item and after navigate somewhere and come back it selected 3rd item from last and showed hidden items (named "Gizli" means "Secret") and hide items which are same place...

What is the problem?

Here is also a basic sample by @Pantelis, I made changes to show problem.
[Sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CB98DD0B6654BA09!114)